# combining two regex patters making either one optiona

Tags: regex

I am writing a REGEX for social secuirty number. I want to combine the two regex so that social security number can be accepted like so:

```
123456789
123-45-6789
```

After searching other post on the internet, I came up with something like so:

```
 Regex regx = new Regex("^\\d{9}$");
 Regex regx2 = new Regex("^\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$");
```

Can I combine them together so that if the user enters 12345678 or 123-45-6789. they both will be valid.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can really only admit one or the other SSN version, then I would just combine your two regex patterns using an alternation:

```
^(?:\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})$
```

### Demo

Answer (score 4):

You can use `?`s to make the `-`s optional (you can read more about it here, https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html). You can then use a backreference for the first `-`. `(-?)` creates the backrefernce and `\\1` is its usage.

```
^\\d{3}(-?)\\d{2}\\1\\d{4}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/Q0zR5e/2/

Comment: Note that this would allow `123-456789`.  Maybe the OP would want this or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the regex as pattern bellow, if you wants one or other:

```
^\\d{3}(\\d{6}|-\\d{2}-\\d{4})$
```